# Wordpress Google Mapping System

Tags: google-maps, wordpress

I need a wordpress google map plugin that will allow me to have a large google map with multiple pins. I have looked up and down and cannot find what I need. Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend using [WP Google Maps](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-google-maps/) It does exactly what you're asking for.

If you feel that that is not enough, check out [Comprehensive Google Maps Plugin.](http://wordpress.org/plugins/comprehensive-google-map-plugin) It has a lot of extra features that you did not mention.